# efficiently looping through pandas dataframe columns to make new dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, random

I want select 200 titles randomly(the correct title shall appear only once in the window) for each question and create a new dataframe. Here I am using list and for loop to do that which is taking a great of time since I have around 80k questions. All 80k questions are unique while around 8K titles are unique.

I have this following code

```
import random
questions = new_df['question_string'].tolist()
titles = new_df['titles'].tolist()
indexs = new_df['image_index'].tolist()

# print(len(titles))
# titles.remove(titles[0])
full_list = []
for x in range(len(questions)):
    full_list.append([questions[x], titles[x], indexs[x], 1])
    t = new_df.titles.unique().tolist()
    if t.count(titles[x])> 0:
        t.remove(titles[x])
    for y in random.choices(t, k=199):
        full_list.append([questions[x], y, indexs[x], 0])

len(full_list)
full_list_df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
full_list_df.columns =['questions', 'titles', 'image_index', 'is_similar']
```

I need help to do this more efficiently, may be using the dataframe driectly.

This is how my dataframe looks like

```
    question_string                                     titles                                             image_index is_similar
0   In how many countries, is the net taxes in con...   Net taxes on products in different countries i...   33715   1
1   In how many countries, is the gross enrolment ...   Total enrollments of female students in school...   68226   1
2   In how many years, is the percentage of popula...   Percentage of the population living below the ...   152731  1
3   What is the ratio of the enrollment rate in pr...   Net enrolment rate in primary and secondary ed...   27823   1
4   In how many countries, is the contraceptive pr...   Percentage of women of different countries who...   72232   1
```

Comment: Have a look to dataframe sample method that allow you to randomly sample rows from it with or without replacement.